# JavaScript interactive map

Tags: javascript, api, interactive

I am creating an interactive map and am using the amcharts API.

I want to be able to hover over a country and have more than the title of the country appear.

I made this [jsFiddle account for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/SnowboardBruin/Bpn7r/4/). You should be able to hover over United States or Australia for additional text.

The folks at amcharts told me to do the following, but they didn't say where to put the code, and any place I try doesn't make sense.

```
{
id: "US-AK",
value: 626932,
description:"this is some more info"
}

And tell the balloon to display it:

areasSettings: {
autoZoom: true,
balloonText: "[[title]]<br>[[description]]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, it'll make looking through things a LOT easier, if you don't have us digging through links to get to the code you want inspected (your fiddle links to a dropbox file.... which is what needs edited).

However, I digress; it's as easy as editing like this:

```
"g":{
            "path":[
                {
                    "id":"AE",
                    "title":"United Arab Emirates",
                    "d":"M619.87,393.72L620.37,393.57L620.48,394.41L622.67,393.93L624.99,394.01L626.68,394.1L628.6,392.03L630.7,390.05L632.47,388.15L633,389.2L633.38,391.64L631.95,391.65L631.72,393.65L632.22,394.07L630.95,394.67L630.94,395.92L630.12,397.18L630.05,398.39L629.48,399.03L621.06,397.51L619.98,394.43z"
                    "description":"this is some more info"
                },
```

in `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103195812/worldLow.js`, and then:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {

    "type": "map",
    "theme": "none",
    "pathToImages":       "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",

    "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
},
    "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true,
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]<br>[[description]]"
},
    "smallMap": {}
});
```

If that all makes sense.  Add your data using whatever label you want in `worldLow.js`, and then put that label in your `baloonText`.

Comment: nice! i was looking at the docs http://docs.amcharts.com/2/javascriptcharts/AmChart but my MapData: [] .. wasnt doing anything